# "Was Warned that ..." (correct word choice / use of passive?)

Tags: word-choice, passive-voice

I am trying to write out a short speech to say after my companies morning exercises, and I have chosen the very  exciting topic of ... the weather!

Anyway I wish to convey this meaning in my sentence:

> I was also warned that Japan has very hot summers and that I should be careful

So far I have:

> すごい暑い夏があるので、気を付けてくださいも言い聞かせられました

I am wondering a few things:

1. Is the choice of 言い聞かせる appropriate, or does it have too sever of a meaning?
2. Is the use of passive voice appropriate here? In my mind it definitely is but I am not confident in that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was also warned that Japan has very hot summers and that I should be careful.

How about...

> 日本の夏はとても(orすごく)暑いので気をつけるように、とも言われました。

「～～ように(と)言う」 means "tell someone to do~~".
Its passive form is 「～～ように(と)言われる」"I am told to do~~"
The も in と**も**言われました means "also".
<sup>(We don't say ～～よう**に、も**言われました.)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend:

そして、「日本の夏はとても暑いので気を付けなさい」を言われました。

The initial そして　to correspond to "also", assuming you used also as a link to your previous sentence.
すごい may be a bit too colloquial for the purpose, so とても works better.

The choice of the form of the verb to use in "I was warned" depends on who warned you, if the warning was addressed to only you, and to whom you are describing having received the warning, so there could be some variation here. In one extreme it could be 気をつけろって言われた and in the other (not maybe yet extreme) would be the one you wrote above.

Comment: `「...気を付けなさい」を言われました。` ← ううん…「『...気をつけなさい』 **と** 言われました。」って言います。（×を→◎と）

Comment: (In a positive meaning) アイカワラズ (I sure hope I got this one right, katakana just just to minimize the risk、だって、さらに迷惑をかけたくない). 本当のこと（。。。またか「を」のことどうしよう？じゃー「を」でいきまーす。。。）を言うとChocolate様みたいなひとはいっぱいいたら直すだでではなく正し回答まで出せるけれども”limited resource"ですので確かにこれは一番効率が高いやり方でしょう。あるがとう！

Comment: またか、ごめんなさい、「あるがとう」はわざと書かなかったんですよ。